# Valve cover gasket sealant causing bad fit

Tags: toyota, oil-leak

Is it possible that too much sealant for a valve cover gasket is causing a bad fit for the gasket, which in turn causes an oil leak? It is a 2006 Toyota Tacoma V6. I do lose quite a bit of oil. I replaced it some years ago and followed the manual to first attach the gasket to the cover with some adhesive/sealant (white stuff) so I am wondering if I used too much.

[image]

Also, is it possible that the visible concentration of black sediment shown here is an indication of an oil leak location?

Here is the outside of where I am suspecting the leak. You can see that the left engine bank has no black oily stain like it is on the right. The black sediment on the inside corresponds to where you see an empty (VVT position) sensor socket on the right.

[image]

Comment: Most common cause of valve cover and pan gaskets is overtightening.  Check the manual for torque.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I followed the torque spec last time to a tee. Order and everything